# Personal, Subpoena'd Information that's Exculpatory is 'Missing'

Tags: criminal-law, evidence, judge, discovery

If information is acquired by a prosecutor that is potentially exculpatory but misplaced, what should a defense attorney do, and what (beyond admonishment) would a judge ordinarily do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to go back to the source of the information, which you indicate was subpoenaed, to see if they have a copy and might be willing to re-send it.

Comment: If they didn't, let's say, acquire just a copy, I'm wondering what a good defense attorney might do.

Comment: Probably try for [adverse inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverse_inference), but it depends on how convincingly the defense attorney can argue the evidence would likely have been exculpatory.